# How to write unit test case for onitemclick for list view using Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

Can anybody tell me how can I check that clicking on an item in list view is triggered properly using Robolectric test case?

Answer (score 0):

you can *fake* `onItemClick` through [ListView.performItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#performItemClick(android.view.View,%20int,%20long))

From the documentation:

> Call the OnItemClickListener, if it is defined. Performs all normal
>   actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility event,
>   playing a sound, etc.